# understanding solution to reward indicator problem

Tags: probability

On a recent homework question I was asked:

Consider a sequence of independent tosses of a biased coin at times $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots , n$. On each toss, the probability of Heads is $p$, and the probability of Tails is $1-p$.

A reward of one unit is given at time $k$, for $k \in \{ 1,2,\ldots ,n\}$, if the toss at time $k$ resulted in Tails and the toss at time $k-1$ resulted in Heads. Otherwise, no reward is given at time $k$.

The answer is:

Let R be the sum of the rewards collected at times $1,2,\ldots ,n$.

The total reward over all the tosses, $R$, is the sum of all the $I_ k$'s, for $k=1,2,\ldots ,n$. By linearity of expectations, we have
$${\bf E}[R] = {\bf E}\left[ \sum _{k=1}^ n I_ k \right] = \sum _{k=1}^ n {\bf E}\left[ I_ k \right] = np(1-p).$$

---

As I understand the problem, the reward requires heads followed by tails and occurs with probability $p(1-p)$. It's impossible to earn a reward on every coin flip. The best you could do is to earn a reward every other flip.

My approach was to bake this intuition into my solution and count only the even flips as follows:

${\bf E}[R] = \sum \limits_{k=1}^ {n/2} 2k p(1-p)$

I'm trying to figure out why this reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: What is this $i$ in your last equation?

Comment: But your formula gives the same result as the other (assuming this $i$ is a typo) so there is nothing wrong...

Comment: That was a typo. Maybe my algebra went wrong? I ended up with $2p(1-p)\frac{(n/2)(n/2+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+2)}{4} p(1-p) $

Comment: Why do you have then this $k$ there? Are you sure you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is incorrect because you're looking at one particular sequence. What the expectation calculates is the average reward over all sequences. So while in a particular sequence, getting a reward at k=1 implies you cannot get a reward at k=2, there are other *realizations* of the sequence where you don't get a reward at k=1, and get one at k=2. The reward is being averaged over all sequences.